# Highlight Currently Selected menu in Listbox Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Hi everyone,
            I have used the listbox to create horizontal menu, i am facing an issue that selected menu is not getting highlighted.

Below is my XAML page

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                    Duration="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                    Duration="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="border" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"  Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <StackPanel x:Name="insidestack"  >
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleofAccess}" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="20" Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"  />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

```
                <ListBox Name="MenuListbox" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Tapped="MenuListbox_SelectionChanged" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" SelectionMode="Single">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

And below is my data as attached  [ItemSource for ListBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCXr4.png)

Still i cant get the selected menu as highlighted one. Any help on this will be very helpful to overcome the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Hi chirag

See the attached item[image: News and Life style lies bottom not in center]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code inside the listbox.

```
<ListBox Name="MenuListbox" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Tapped="MenuListbox_SelectionChanged" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="insidestack">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleofAccess}"
                                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                       TextAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="10"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Hi chirag.. Thank you for your response. ITs not working for me. Please suggest some other way

Comment: Hi Chirag, the list lists down vertically not horizontally.

Comment: Hi Chirag its not aligned centre, its aligned in bottom

Comment: whats aligned in bottom? the listbox or the items in it? if possible add a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

So, there's several things about your templating I would change. However for your immediate question swap your current Frame animation;

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                               Duration="0">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
       </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

With a direct `ColorAnimation` at the proper `UIElement` target property to look like;

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                Duration="0" To="White" />
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

ADDED:

So since I hardly ever actually test my answers (bad habit I know, but generally they're going to be correct.) In this scenario I don't have time to anyway but here's what I'd do guaranteed to work and is better form anyway.

Take what you have here;

```
<StackPanel x:Name="border" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"  Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <StackPanel x:Name="insidestack"  >
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleofAccess}" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="20" Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"  />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </StackPanel>
```

Since I don't understand why you would need the StackPanel or the ContentControl like that, swap it like this (minimal change, but if it were me I'd refactor all of it);

```
<Grid>
<Border x:Name="SelectedState" Background="Red" Visibility="Collapsed">
 <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"  
                 Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                 Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                 VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">

      <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleofAccess}" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="20" Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"  />

  </ContentControl>

</Grid>
```

Then just toggle the visibility of the one Border in there to provide your background like shown below. We do this because it's better to toggle one object, instead of a lot of properties separately (which will give you warnings for doing so for a reason);

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedState">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
```

Sorry I don't have time to format things pretty. However I want to reiterate, it's obvious you're new to how templating and the VisualStateManager works, I would consider refactoring this control overall even if it is small changes necessary, as it sits a lot of parts of it don't make sense as to why they were done the way you have them. Cheers

Comment: Hi Chris thank you for looking into my issue. Its not working for me. Still i didn't get highlighted menu. Please give some other option